# Splitting string in r while first column stays same

Tags: r, string, split

Title might need some editing since I am not sure how to explain effectively.

here I have two columns and second column might have 3 object in same row but split by "|". I wrote a code to split them and write next line after dropping ***MESH:*** however It adds extra digit to first column. First row is not always 6 digits therefore a function I wrote is not helpful in here. Here is an example data

```
chem11
       ChemicalID                                                chem
    1     C089250           MESH:D000075163|MESH:D000688|MESH:D005296
    2     C114385                           MESH:D009842|MESH:D010069
    3     C114386                                        MESH:D009842
    4     C434150                                        MESH:D006576
    5     C434149                                        MESH:D006576
    6  C000620092                           MESH:D010793|MESH:D052117
    7     C533344                                        MESH:D006576
    8     C533345                                        MESH:D006576
    9     C046983 MESH:D003630|MESH:D008727|MESH:D011239|MESH:D014750
    10    C585814                           MESH:D013876|MESH:D052117
    11    C533898                                        MESH:D010455
    12    C493119                           MESH:D009281|MESH:D012717
    13    C014305                                        MESH:D015107
    14    C473129                                        MESH:D011092
    21    C040211                                        MESH:D000630
    22    C033472                                        MESH:D000166
    23 C000599298                           MESH:D000166|MESH:D010795
```

The code would work

```
# expand duplicated DrugBank IDs
chemtmp = vector('list', nrow(chem11))
for (i in 1:nrow(chem11)) chemtmp[[i]] = as.character(chem11[i, 2])
names(chemtmp) = as.character(chem11[, 1])
chemtmp = sapply(chemtmp, strsplit, split = '\\|')
tmp = unlist(chemtmp)
chem2 = data.frame(IDs = tmp, ChemicalID = names(tmp))
chem2[, 1] = gsub('MESH:', '', chem2[, 1])
```

if every element of first row 7 digits, next code would work but there are some longer ones and I cannot figure a way to solve.

```
String2=function(data,from,to)
{
  B2=NULL
  for(i in 1:length(data)){B2[[i]]=paste0(data[[i]][from:to],collapse = "")}
  B2=unlist(B2)
  return(B2)
}
ChemID=String2(B1,1,7)
```

Expected output should be

```
          XXX        YYY
1     C089250 D000075163
2     C089250    D000688
3     C089250    D005296
4     C114385    D009842
5     C114385    D010069
6     C114386    D009842
7     C434150    D006576
8     C434149    D006576
9  C000620092    D010793
10 C000620092    D052117
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the `"MESH:"` part from `chem` column and separate data into different rows based on `"|"`.

```
library(dplyr)

chem11 %>%
  mutate(chem = gsub('MESH:', '', chem)) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(chem, sep = '\\|')

# A tibble: 27 x 2
#   ChemicalID chem      
#   <chr>      <chr>     
# 1 C089250    D000075163
# 2 C089250    D000688   
# 3 C089250    D005296   
# 4 C114385    D009842   
# 5 C114385    D010069   
# 6 C114386    D009842   
# 7 C434150    D006576   
# 8 C434149    D006576   
# 9 C000620092 D010793   
#10 C000620092 D052117   
# … with 17 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you. I am curious. How did you read the sample data? or how did you create it `chem11`

Comment: `chem11 <- read.table(text = 'copy-paste data from the post', header = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

You can set `into = c(NA, "chem")` in `separate()` to remove `"MESH:"` part, and `fill = "left"` is to deal with some `chem` which don't start with `"MESH:"`.

```
library(tidyr)

chem11 %>%
  separate_rows(chem, sep = '\\|') %>%
  separate(chem, c(NA, "chem"), sep = ':', fill = "left")

# # A tibble: 27 x 2
#    ChemicalID chem      
#    <chr>      <chr>     
#  1 C089250    D000075163
#  2 C089250    D000688   
#  3 C089250    D005296   
#  4 C114385    D009842   
#  5 C114385    D010069   
#  6 C114386    D009842   
#  7 C434150    D006576   
#  8 C434149    D006576   
#  9 C000620092 D010793   
# 10 C000620092 D052117   
# # … with 17 more rows
```

---

***Data***

```
chem11 <- structure(list(ChemicalID = c("C089250", "C114385", "C114386", 
"C434150", "C434149", "C000620092", "C533344", "C533345", "C046983", 
"C585814", "C533898", "C493119", "C014305", "C473129", "C040211", 
"C033472", "C000599298"), chem = c("MESH:D000075163|MESH:D000688|MESH:D005296", 
"MESH:D009842|MESH:D010069", "MESH:D009842", "MESH:D006576", 
"MESH:D006576", "MESH:D010793|MESH:D052117", "MESH:D006576", 
"MESH:D006576", "MESH:D003630|MESH:D008727|MESH:D011239|MESH:D014750", 
"MESH:D013876|MESH:D052117", "MESH:D010455", "MESH:D009281|MESH:D012717", 
"MESH:D015107", "MESH:D011092", "MESH:D000630", "MESH:D000166", 
"MESH:D000166|MESH:D010795")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "21", "22", "23"))
```